# Fresh Ubuntu 23.04 does not recognise second display (AMG Gpu)

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I just installed Ubuntu 23.04 after years of not using it. My problem is that ubuntu doesnt recognise my second display (both displays are using HDMI ports), my graphic card is the RX480.

I tried to install the latest AMD drivers(Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 23.10.3 for Ubuntu 22.04.2) but I don´t know if I´m not doing it right or whatever so any light you can point at the problem would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

I did follow [this AMD guide](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
inxi -G 

Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX
    470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] driver: amdgpu
    v: kernel
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.8
    with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8 compositor: gnome-shell
    v: 44.3 driver: dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1280x1024~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1
    renderer: AMD Radeon RX 480 Graphics (polaris10 LLVM
    15.0.7 DRM 3.49 6.2.0-34-generic)


xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     59.89*+
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77 



 lshw -c video

*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: c7
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1280,1024
   resources: irq:143 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:dfe00000-dfe3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```